# How to insert data into map<string, set<string> > C++?

Tags: c++, string, dictionary

I need advice how to insert data into map with `string` and `set<string>`. I tried something like this, but it doesnt work:

```
#include <map>
#include <utility>

int main()
{      
  std::map<string, set<string> > mymap;
  std::map<string, set<string> >::iterator it = mymap.begin(); 

  mymap.insert ( std::pair<string, set<string> > ("car" , "orange") );
  return (0);
}
```

Could someone help me? Thank you in advance.

Comment: `mymap[key] = value;`? Otherwise looks like the second part of your `pair` is not a `set`.

Comment: in C++11, `mymap.insert({"car", {"orange"}});` should work.  The problem with the code in the question is that "orange" is not a set.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Two methods:

```
set<string> myset;
myset.insert("orange");

//first method
mymap["car"] = myset; //will overwrite existing data!!

//second method
mymap.insert(make_pair("car", myset));
```

Comment: these methods are not equivalent

Comment: @lizusek, would you please elaborate? Thanks.

Comment: @RSahu if key is already present in map, insert will not insert, but [] will overwrite, so basically answer given above is not correct since question was about how to 'insert'

Answer (score 10):

I don't know why it seems so popular these days to avoid `operator[]` for maps, it's so much more elegant than `insert`. Unless of course, the slight differences (such as the need for a default constructor) cause it to not work for you, or you've determined that it is causing a performance problem. For your purposes, as you've described them, it should work fine.

```
mymap["car"].insert("orange");
```

This will construct the set if it doesn't already exist, and it will insert an element into it.  In comments, you've expressed a desire to add further elements to the set, and you can use the exact same syntax.

```
mymap["car"].insert("blue");
```

If you want to ensure you have a fresh, empty set before inserting, you can always call `clear()` on it.

```
auto & car_set = mymap["car"];
car_set.clear();
car_set.insert("orange");
```

Comment: This is as elegant as it can get, but I were to use `insert` instead of `operator []` , how can it be done if the key is already present in the map?

Answer (score 4):

```
#include <map>
#include <set>
#include <string>

int main() {
    std::map< std::string, std::set< std::string> > mymap;
    std::set< std::string> s;
    s.insert( "orange");
    mymap.insert( std::make_pair( std::string("car") , s));
    return 0;
}
```

To add new element to existing `std::set`:

```
//add string to set identified by key "car"
if ( mymap.find( "car") != mymap.end()) {
    std::set< std::string>& s_ref = mymap[ "car"];
    s_ref.insert( "blue");
}
```

Please check this [online example](http://ideone.com/I9WZFc).

Comment: Thank you for your answers, it helps me, but I have one more question. If I want to add next string to set? This doesnt work :/ http://pastebin.com/aD3NGNAd

Comment: @user3421673 please take a look at the updated answer

Answer (score 3):

```
#include <map> 
#include <set>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void insertValue(map<string, set<string> >& myMap,
                 string const& key,
                 string const& value)
{
   // Check whether there is already a set given the key.
   // If so, insert to the existing set.
   // Otherwise, create a set and add it to the map.
   map<string, set<string> >::iterator found = myMap.find(key);
   if ( found != myMap.end() )
   {
      cout << "Adding '" << value << "' to an existing set of " << key << "s.\n";
      found->second.insert(value);
   }
   else
   {
      cout << "Adding '" << value << "' to a new set of " << key << "s.\n";
      set<string> temp;
      temp.insert(value);
      myMap.insert(make_pair(key, temp));
   }
}

int main()
{
   map<string, set<string> > mymap;
   insertValue(mymap, "car", "orange");
   insertValue(mymap, "car", "blue");
   insertValue(mymap, "car", "red");
   insertValue(mymap, "truck", "orange");
   insertValue(mymap, "truck", "blue");
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Other than the output statements, your `insertValue` function achieves the exact same thing as simply doing: `mymap[key].insert(value);`